# Is it possible to get these two CSS animations to work with each other?

Tags: css, animation

I have two CSS animations in the same element and they're conflicting with each other. I've seen other answers that say you can assign multiple animations if they are separated by a comma, but those examples are for shorthand animation assignments. Would there be any way to get both of those animations to work together?:

```
.whiteLayer{
-webkit-transform: scale(0);
transform: scale(0);
margin-top: 50px;
border-radius: 50%;
width: 475px;
height: 475px;
border: 1px dashed white;
position: absolute;
top: 12px;
margin-left: 8px;
-webkit-animation-name: spin;
-webkit-animation-duration: 60s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
-webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
animation-name: spin;
animation-duration: 60s;
animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-play-state: running;
animation-delay: 2s;


-webkit-animation-name: intro;
-webkit-animation-duration: .2s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-webkit-animation-delay: .2s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
animation-name: intro;
animation-duration: .2s;
animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-delay: .2s;
animation-fill-mode:forwards;


}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

@keyframes spin {
from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes intro{
from {transform: scale(0);}
to {transform: scale(1);}
}

@keyframes intro {
from {transform: scale(0);}
to {transform: scale(1);}
```

Please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to this would be that I create two divs (or one additional div to wrap your current element) and set the other one to the first and so. They would be on separate div's but still looking like they're in just one.

Might need some margin / padding probing to get it all lined up though.

Comment: why two divs when you can achieve the same effect with one?

Answer (score 0):

In your above case the animation at the bottom will override the animation on the top. That's the way how css works. If you want to have both animation working together you need to apply both transform properties together in a single animation i.e apply both scale and rotate in the same animation.

I have setup a demo in this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gkueL/1/

```
.whiteLayer{
    background-color:red;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 275px;
    height: 275px;
    border: 1px dashed white;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 8px;
    -webkit-animation-name: spin;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 60s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0);}
    to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1);}
}
```